# Oracle SQL Average query

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions, average, mean

I need to do an average median with Oracle. I have this:

```
SELECT V.Id_Aeropuerto_Destino AS Id_Aeropuerto, C.Nombre AS Ciudad_Destino, A.nombre AS Aeropuerto,
(SELECT SUM((TO_NUMBER(V.Retraso_Salida,'99999999D99','nls_numeric_characters=''.,''')) + 
        (TO_NUMBER(V.Retraso_Llegada,'99999999D99','nls_numeric_characters=''.,''')))
        FROM Vuelo V
        WHERE V.Id_Aeropuerto_Destino=Id_Aeropuerto) Retraso_Total
FROM Ciudad C, Aeropuerto A, Vuelo V
WHERE V.Id_Aeropuerto_Destino=A.Id_Aeropuerto AND A.Ciudad = C.Id_Ciudad;
```

This calculates the total delay of a number of flights ("Retraso_Total"). Now I need to do an AVG from "Retraso_Total", to get ("Retraso_Total" / number of flights) -> Retraso_Medio, something like this:

```
SELECT V.Id_Aeropuerto_Destino AS Id_Aeropuerto, C.Nombre AS Ciudad_Destino, A.nombre AS Aeropuerto,
(SELECT AVG SUBQUERY) Retraso_Medio,
(SELECT SUM((TO_NUMBER(V.Retraso_Salida,'99999999D99','nls_numeric_characters=''.,''')) + 
        (TO_NUMBER(V.Retraso_Llegada,'99999999D99','nls_numeric_characters=''.,''')))
        FROM Vuelo V
        WHERE V.Id_Aeropuerto_Destino=Id_Aeropuerto) Retraso_Total
FROM Ciudad C, Aeropuerto A, Vuelo V
WHERE V.Id_Aeropuerto_Destino=A.Id_Aeropuerto AND A.Ciudad = C.Id_Ciudad;
```

I try with this:

```
SELECT AVG(SUM((TO_NUMBER(V.Retraso_Salida,'99999999D99','nls_numeric_characters=''.,''')) + 
        (TO_NUMBER(V.Retraso_Llegada,'99999999D99','nls_numeric_characters=''.,'''))))
        FROM Vuelo V
        WHERE V.Id_Aeropuerto_Destino=Id_Aeropuerto
        GROUP BY V.Id_Aeropuerto_Destino) Retraso_Medio
```

But this subquery doesn't work.

How I can do that (all in the same query)?

Thanks!!

Table Vuelo (Flight) has (id_plane, id_origin_airport, id_destiny_airport, id_company, departure hour, arrival hour, departure delay, arrival delay, date, canceled, passengers, milles:

```
CREATE TABLE Vuelo(
    Id_Avion number(4),
    Id_Aeropuerto_Origen number(5),
    Id_Aeropuerto_Destino number(5),
    Id_Aerolinea varchar(2),
    Hora_Salida number(4),
    Hora_Llegada number(4),
    Retraso_Salida varchar(5),
    Retraso_Llegada varchar(5),
    Fecha varchar(10),
    Cancelado varchar(3) NOT NULL,
    Pasajeros varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    Distancia varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_Vuelo PRIMARY KEY(Id_Avion, Id_Aeropuerto_Origen, Fecha, Hora_salida),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Avion FOREIGN KEY(Id_Avion) REFERENCES Avion(Id_Avion),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Aeropuerto_Origen FOREIGN KEY(Id_Aeropuerto_Origen) REFERENCES Aeropuerto(Id_Aeropuerto),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Aeropuerto_Destino FOREIGN KEY(Id_Aeropuerto_Destino) REFERENCES Aeropuerto(Id_Aeropuerto),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Aerolinea FOREIGN KEY(Id_Aerolinea) REFERENCES Aerolinea(Id_Aerolinea),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Fecha FOREIGN KEY(Fecha) REFERENCES Fecha(Id_Fecha)
);
```

Table Ciudad (City) has id_city, name, latitude, longitude, population, timezone:

```
CREATE TABLE Ciudad(
    Id_Ciudad number(7),
    Nombre varchar(80) NOT NULL,
    Latitud varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    Longitud varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    Habitantes number(10) NOT NULL,
    Timezone varchar(80) NOT NULL,  
    CONSTRAINT pk_Ciudad PRIMARY KEY(Id_Ciudad)
);
```

Table Aeropuerto (Airport) has id_airport, name, code, id_city, state, state_code:

```
CREATE TABLE Aeropuerto(
    Id_Aeropuerto number(5),
    Nombre varchar(80) NOT NULL,
    Codigo varchar(4) NOT NULL,
    Ciudad number(5) NOT NULL,
    Estado varchar(80) NOT NULL,
    Codigo_Estado varchar(4) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_Aeropuerto PRIMARY KEY(Id_Aeropuerto),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Ciudad FOREIGN KEY(Ciudad) REFERENCES Ciudad(Id_Ciudad)
);
```

Comment: Sum of aggregate with non aggregates.. what are you trying to do? Explain it a little

Comment: I need to calculate the total delay of a number of flights ("Retraso Total") and the mean of this ("Retraso Total" / number of flights). Sorry for my english

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected output and rules of the calculations

Comment: ok, here we go!

Comment: i just added my tables

Comment: Please explain, in plain English, what you are trying to do. The query you wrote has no chance to work - you are selecting from three tables, `V, A, C` but in the `from ` clause you have only one table. You say you want to compute total and average delays, but your query selects airport names as well. Etc. Don't make us guess just based on your query, which is obviously incorrect.

Comment: ok, the complete query i need to get id_airport, city name, delay mean and total delay. i have everything but i dont know how get the delay mean

Comment: i need to add the mean delay at the first query of my post

Comment: Not related to your question, but I think it is worth mentioning: Use ENGLISH language not only to post questions in this site but also to name all the objects in your code. This is best practice, specially when you need to share your code (like in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments it seems you want to calculate a MEAN rather than a MEDIAN as your question's opening line says.

This is quite simple. The Oracle `AVG()` function calculates the mean for us, without the need to derive totals and counts. Obviously it's still messy, due to the casting because table uses strings to store numeric values.

An average is an aggregate function, so we need to group by the non-aggregate columns. In your example that means the destination airport ID, City and Name. So this should work for you:

```
SELECT V.Id_Aeropuerto_Destino AS Id_Aeropuerto
        , C.Nombre AS Ciudad_Destino
        , A.nombre AS Aeropuerto
        , AVG((TO_NUMBER(V.Retraso_Salida,'99999999D99','nls_numeric_characters=''.,''')) + 
        (TO_NUMBER(V.Retraso_Llegada,'99999999D99','nls_numeric_characters=''.,''')))
         as "Retraso_Total"
FROM Vuelo V
     join Aeropuerto A 
         on V.Id_Aeropuerto_Destino=A.Id_Aeropuerto 
     join Ciudad C
         on  A.Ciudad = C.Id_Ciudad
group by V.Id_Aeropuerto_Destino 
        , C.Nombre 
        , A.nombre 
/
```

Comment: Thanks! but i dont understand why you do this: / count(*) as "Retraso_Total".

Comment: Other thing, if i execute this i get numers like:     ,705376344     -,01055565 in "Retraso_Total"

Comment: The `/ count(*)` was an editing error. Try the query without it

Comment: As for the formatting, I have used your formatting exactly as you posted it. You haven't bothered to provide us with sample data, so I cannot explain what results you get.